# AMPscript - If Contains

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In an AMPscript If statement, is there a way to use "contains" as the operator?
For example:

If Var1 Contains "Dog" Then do this

Would I just have to use a regular Expression?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [IndexOf()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IndexOf) function to do that.

```
%%[ 
Var @str, @var, @msg 

/* Set the value to check */ 
Set @var = "Dog" 

/* Set the string to check */ 
Set @str = "MyDogIsMyFriend" 

/* Does it match */ 
if IndexOf(@str,@var) > 0 then 
    Set @msg = "We Found It" 
else 
    Set @msg = "We didn't find it" 
endif 

]%% 
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```

I've been looking for the same solution and I found the answer to the similar question on [3sixty](https://3sixty.exacttarget.com/Connect/Answers/QuestionDetails/tabid/69/ContentID/4286/Default.aspx).